# Measuring before and after results of a treatment with N people and K trials per person

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, t-test, pre-post-comparison

Let's say I have a group of 10 students and I want to study the effect of a treatment on their memory.

I will have them each take 20 indistinguishable memory tests.  Then I will administer the treatment and give them another round of 20 indistinguishable memory tests.

How would I make use of the fact that I have an extra 'dimension' of data here? in the form of 20 tests rather than one single test?  I also know that before the treatment, each student's test score variance will be much higher than after the treatment.

One option is to just take the mean score of each student and do a t-test of some sort, or I could do 10 separate t-tests for each student...but somehow I feel like there should be a way to combine all of this information into one statistical test.

EDIT: I want to be able to say that the treatment had a statistically significant improvement and maybe give an idea of by how much. There is also an issue that the highest test score of the student matters in some sense so maybe use that as a metric as well. I have a vector of data for each student instead of just one term. The reason I say highest test score matters in some sense is that the actual scenario has to do with algorithms searching for optimal configurations. Each configuration has a certain accuracy. So if you can find a configuration with the best accuracy you can then reuse that configuration. So even if the average score of the 20 different configurations you find is better. If one method was able to find the single best configuration but have worse average accuracy that would still matter for something.

I think this is a question of multiple hypothesis testing.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Cross Validated! Can you explain what you want to achieve with such a test?

Comment: @utobi (so yeah this is just an analogy for the actual business use case that I have) but I want to be able to say that the treatment had a statistically significant improvement and maybe give an idea of by how much.  There is also an issue that the highest test score of the student matters in some sense so maybe use that as a metric as well.

Comment: You could then take the difference between the two measures for each student and then apply a simple t-test. In other terms, you have to apply a t-test for paired data. I'm not sure what you mean by " There is also an issue that the highest test score of the student matters in some sense so maybe use that as a metric as well" but the average takes into account also the maximum.

Comment: @utobi well here I have a vector of data for each student instead of just one term.  The reason I say highest test score matters in some sense is that the actual scenario has to do with algorithms searching for optimal configurations. Each configuration has a certain accuracy. So if you can find a configuration with the best accuracy you can then reuse that configuration.  So even if the average score of the 20 different configurations you find is better. If one method was able to find the single best configuration but have worse average accuracy that would still matter for something.

Comment: Please add new  information as an edit to the post and not only as comments. On this site, comments are ephemeral, often seen be few, and can be deleted